Should we volunteer as a "sister site" for Parenting?
I know that we've talking about attempting to merge with different sites, but this would be different.  Parenting has a Some subjects might be on-topic here but you can get better response on our sister sites, for instance: clause in their FAQ, where they include Fitness and Nutrition and a handful of other sites.
I'm not sure what the process would be to approach the mods of Parenting (whether contacting them directly or via their per-site Meta), but what does the community think about trying to get our site included as a spot where parents could ask more theoretical questions on the psychological aspects of parenting or child development(without getting into the self-help category, obviously)?  
I'm certain this would not be a major flow of traffic, but every little bit helps.  

Standard procedure would just be ask "Do we want to be in Parent's FAQ" on here and ask "Do you want Cog Sci in your FAQ" over there as meta questions. Already did that for Workplace and Programmers but I'm waiting to pull the trigger (they've been a bit crappy with migrating bad questions this week)

Might also be worth a mention in Bio too, since they have at least two Meta questions asking about Cog Sci questions, not sure Parenting would have as much interest really.

@BenBrocka The only thing about parenting is there may be a lot of well-read parents that want to know more about the details of child development and aren't sure where to ask

Is anyone an active user on parenting?

Ah, that's true. Sounds like the Autism site is unlikely to be helpful there anyway. Don't know anyone that's active on Parenting...might want to ask the Parenting mods in the Teacher's Lounge

Someone could advertise the dev-psych tag or related tags on parenting's meta :D.

My question on their Meta: http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/357/cognitive-sciences-cogsci-se-would-like-to-offer-its-services

Parenting mod here. I think we'd be glad to update our FAQ, although I'll hold off until you reach a consensus here as to whether you want that.

@Beofett Fantastic!  I've brought your comment up in our chat, so we should be able to arrive at an definitive answer for you.

@Beofett Please see Jeromy's answer below.

As a moderator, I'd certainly welcome more scientific questions about child psychology on cogsci.se. 
I have had a look around Parenting.se and it, naturally, has a very different culture to cogsci.SE. There are many questions on Parenting.SE seeking general advice on parenting. And many answers are based on personal experience of existing parents. But there are some answers that source scientific research.
Thus, @Beofett I would welcome an addition to your FAQ along the lines of:

Scientific questions about child psychology (see the developmental-psychology tag on Cognitive Sciences SE)

That said, I wouldn't be surprised if that might be a bit too broad for the liking of moderators on Parenting.SE. 

Thanks Jeromy!  Well, we can always discuss it and make adjustments, but that's right along the lines of what I was thinking.

@Chuck Thanks for developing these "sister site" ideas.

I'm going to hold off until our other active moderator returns in about a week or so, as I'd like to discuss the specific wording with him. We do try and encourage answers that source scientific research, so we'll have to have some discussion as to where the boundaries lie. Thanks!

Not sure I like the use of the phrase "child psychology"...
